# Optimizations in pointers and references?

Tags: c#, pointers, reference

I did the  following simple experiment with pointers and references.
I made two functions `Swap` and `SwapByReference` whose code is given below:-

```
 void Swap(int* num1, int* num2)
 {
      int temp = *num1 ; 
      *num1 = *num2 ; 
      *num2 = temp ; 
  }
 void SwapByReference(ref int num1, ref int num2)
 {
      int temp ; 
      temp = num1 ; 
      num1 = num2 ; 
      num2 = temp ; 
 }
```

Then, I took a `List<int>` and added 100 million values to it using a for loop. 
After that I called both `Swap` and `SwapByReference` functions on the list like this.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < MaxValue - 1; i++)
        {
            int num1 = list1[i] ;  // num1p and num2p are of type int*
                                   // MaxValue is equal to 100 million.
                                  // list1 is of type List<int> which contains MaxValue elements in it.
            int num2 = list1[i+1] ; 
            num1p = &num1 ; 
            num2p = &num2 ;  
            Swap(num1p, num2p);
        }
```

and

```
    for (int i = 0; i < MaxValue - 1; i++)
        {
            int num1 = list1[i];
            int num2 = list1[i + 1];
            SwapByReference(ref num1, ref num2);
        }
```

After that I ran this code for different values of `MaxValue` like 100 million, 10 million, 1 million,(with and without optimizations) and noted the  observations about the time taken in running the above code, and calculated the difference b/w optimized and not optimized code for different MaxValue for both pointers and reference.
 **100 million**

> Swap function = 5509.6
>   SwapByReference function = 5549.5

**10 million**

> Swap function = 553.6
>   SwapByReference function = 718.6

**1 million**

> Swap function = 37.6
>   SwapByReference = 56.8

All the above observations are in milliseconds and I use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to measure the time.
My question is that why is the optimization more in case of references as compared to pointers?
Is there anything special about references in this case?

Comment: Why are you bothering with a list at all? You're not actually swapping the values *in* the list... you're swapping two local variables.

Comment: Actually, my main purpose was to measure the optimization when both the `Swap` and `SwapByReference` functions run millions of times. I am using `List<int>` just to store a set of different numbers

Comment: So why not just use local variables based on `i`? That way there'll be less interference from other things such as the list values having to swap into memory. It doesn't help that you haven't shown your benchmarking code, either. Do you have an actual purpose for this? Have you determined that using `ref` is a bottleneck in a *real* program?

Comment: I had heard from many people that using pointers and references  can greatly increase performance, so just wanted to know which one will perform better,and in the mean time noticed the mentioned pattern.

Comment: It turns out that references share the same memory address as the object they reference, so the swap probably performs a tad faster. Whereas the pointer has to reach out to the address it points to in order to get the relevant data. If I am mistaken, someone please correct me.

Comment: @user1274223 Although what you have said seems to be true to me but,when I compared the  time taken in swapping, it didn't had a pattern. Both the functions outperformed each other many times(sometimes `Swap` was faster, sometimes `SwapByReference` was faster), also I wanted to know why is optimization more in case of references as compared to pointers.

Comment: @ps06756 When posting benchmark results you should post also standard deviations along with averages.

Comment: The results I had posted were average.

Comment: @ps06756: This sounds like premature optimization to me. I would personally avoid pointers unless you *really* need them, and even avoid `ref` unless you've got a good reason to use it. First write the simplest code that works, and then see whether it meets your (predefined) performance goals. If it doesn't *then* you should investigate where it's suboptimal.

Comment: You are not profiling correctly, this takes just as much time.  A hundred million swaps takes ~0.30 seconds on my poky laptop.  You don't have the optimizer enabled.

Comment: You say that sometimes one is faster, sometimes the other. Why are you concluding that `SwapByReference` is faster? It seems your measurement cannot distinguish which one is faster and they might just be about equal. As your program is side-effect free you might see that an optimizing JIT just deletes everything. Your benchmark is therefore invalid.

Comment: I am not saying that `SwapByReference` is faster. I am just saying that it gets more better(less time) if we run the code with optimization.

Comment: Where are the numbers with optimization? Use Ctrl-F5 and Release mode.